# Unable to boot in default user mode in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, root

I executed the following commands on Ubuntu 14.04 taken from [How to Become Root in Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Ubuntu):
`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
`sudo passwd root`
`sudo -i`

Once I restarted my computer I am getting the following error:

```
The system is not able to boot for user "ravi".
To stop booting for "ravi" press S and for manual repair press M
```

How to login as root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first of all, that's not how you become root in ubuntu. To become root, you can either use the `sudo` command to execute root, or you can use `sudo passwd` which is how to set the password for the root account on ubuntu. Then, to become root, you use `su` and enter the password you set previously.

Did you edit anything in the fstab document?

Comment: I didn't edit anything in fstab.